# need an image of a shadow underneath my images that use that class

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to use the above image in a img class to put underneath the photos. That have that class. See the markup example below.

```
<img class="img-shadow" src="image.jpg">
```

or may be like this

```
<div class="img-shadow">
   <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

How would the css look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="img-shadow">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-shadow{
    background:url(your image URL) no-repeat center bottom;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Adjust the padding on the bottom of the div to increase or decrease the distance between the bottom of the image and the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

If what you said in the question is what you really want to do, You can simply put the shadow image below the other image using an `<img>` tag like

```
<div>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSyLdxqT0UBb31xeB4yMfUjCqKld2q9FqpUMZEIvq175_4-MgAPUA"/> //Your image
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLAht.png"/> // Your shadow image
</div>
```

and position them accordingly using css..

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/eGCu5/7/)

*Note:there might be better ways for creating a shadow below an image, just answering the question in a straight forward manner..*

Answer (score 0):

Just as another option, instead of using an image for your shadow, you can use CSS3 shadow property to achieve something similar.

In the fiddle, I show the same image using the class and not using the class: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGCu5/8/)

```
   .img-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #000;
    width: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: yes I may have exhausted the "box-shadow" idea. Did you see the image above? I want it to look like that [under the image]... Do you know a way of doing that with "box-shadow" ? Other wise I need to use the image.